# New to Angular 9, redirecting works but going directly to URL does not

Tags: angular

I have a very simple routing module in Angular 9.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CalculatorsComponent } from './calculators/calculators.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'calculators', component: CalculatorsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/calculators', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm running a local server, and when I go to `http://localhost:4200`, it properly redirects me to `http://localhost:4200/calculators`. However, if I try to access `http://localhost:4200/calculators` directly either by entering it in  my address bar or by refreshing the page after it redirects, I get a 404 status code and `Cannot GET /calculators` as a response.

I feel like this is just how Angular works as a Single Page Application, but please correct me if I'm wrong. If this is expected, how would I deal with my website when a user tries to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/calculators`. I would expect that they *should* be able to access that URL without having to navigate through the root view to the `/calculators` view.

Comment: You need to configure the server for redirecting to `index.html` file. If you use `apache`, for example, you need to configure `.htaccess` file. This may help you : https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566

Comment: As Harun said. You need to config/write rewrite rules. What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using a NodeJS server with Express. When I'm developing, I'm using the Angular CLI and "ng serve --open".

Comment: I think I found a link on the Angular page about this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration. I'll take a look at it--didn't know about this prior to all of your replies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you run the angular app.

If it's inside of nginx or apache you need to configure rewrites.

for nginx

```
    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

for apache you need to add / change .htaccess in the root dir

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```